# Scala - Lower bound inference in path-dependent types

Tags: scala, type-inference, path-dependent-type

I'm trying to understand why can't the Scala compiler infer the following restriction on a path-dependent type:

```
trait MyTrait
class MyTraitImpl extends MyTrait
trait MyTrait2[A <: MyTrait] {
  type MyTraitType = A
}
class MyTrait2Impl[A <: MyTrait] extends MyTrait2[A]

val obj: MyTrait2[_] = new MyTrait2Impl[MyTraitImpl]

def myMethod[A <: MyTrait](t2: MyTrait2[A]) = println("Hi!")

myMethod[obj.MyTraitType](obj)
// <console>:14: error: type arguments [obj.MyTraitType] do not conform to method myMethod's type parameter bounds [A <: MyTrait]
//               myMethod[obj.MyTraitType](obj)
```

For me, intuitively, `MyTraitType` can't be anything other than a subclass of a `MyTrait`, as the bound is right on `A` in `MyTrait2`. If there is, can you give me an example or point me to where this code snippet is wrong?

If this is a Scala compiler limitation, can anyone show me a way to achieve this using the type system? Note that:

- I do not have a `MyTrait` object, nor does `myMethod` receive one;
- I do not need `myMethod` to know the concrete type of `A`; all it needs to know is that `A` it is a subtype of `MyTrait` and that `t2` is parametrized on `A`;
- The underscore in `obj` is intentional; where I call `myMethod`, I don't know the concrete type of `A` (or else it would not be a problem);
- I prefer solutions where I don't have to modify `myMethod`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use constraints on type member instead of bounds on type parameter in `MyTrait2` declaration:

```
trait MyTrait
class MyTraitImpl extends MyTrait
trait MyTrait2 { // Remove [A <: MyTrait]
  type MyTraitType <: MyTrait // add <: MyTrait
}
class MyTrait2Impl[A <: MyTrait] extends MyTrait2 { type MyTraitType = A }

val obj: MyTrait2 = new MyTrait2Impl[MyTraitImpl]

def myMethod[A <: MyTrait](t2: MyTrait2{ type MyTraitType = A }) = println("Hi!")

myMethod[obj.MyTraitType](obj)
```

You'll get a compilation error on wrong types, just as expected:

```
scala> val otherObj: MyTrait2 = new MyTrait2Impl[MyTraitImpl]
otherObj: MyTrait2 = MyTrait2Impl@8afcd0c

scala> myMethod[obj.MyTraitType](otherObj)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : otherObj.type (with underlying type MyTrait2)
 required: MyTrait2{type MyTraitType = obj.MyTraitType}
              myMethod[obj.MyTraitType](otherObj)
                                        ^
```

Proof it works with `List[MyTrait2]`:

```
scala> for {
     |   obj <- List[MyTrait2](
     |            new MyTrait2Impl[MyTraitImpl],
     |            new MyTrait2Impl[MyTraitImpl]
     |          )
     | } myMethod[obj.MyTraitType](obj)
Hi!
Hi!
```

Comment: That way it works indeed, but it is kind of a workaround for the underscore in the original question. In your solution, the call works because the compiler knows the concrete type `A` in `obj`, whereas in my example I explicitly suppressed it. Imagine now that I have a `List[MyTrait2]` and I want to call `myMethod` with one of the elements; it won't work with both solutions. However, in my mind, I think it should, as there are concrete bounds (`<: MyTrait`) on what types can `A` take.

Comment: @RuiGoncalves: my solution works with `List[MyTrait2]` just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking this long in evaluating your solution in my specific case. I tested it and it indeed worked. I ended up defining a `type Alias[A] = MyTrait2{ type MyTraitType = A }`, which hid the somewhat uglier syntax needed to reference the `myMethod`'s parameter type, which I use a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep the generic parameter (I do agree, abstract types would be nicer in this case), you can do the following:

Restrict the wildcard type of `obj`:

```
val obj: MyTrait2[_ <: MyTrait] = new MyTrait2Impl[MyTraitImpl]
```

Call `myMethod` without type parameters and let the compiler figure it out:

```
myMethod(obj)
```

This is nothing more than helping the compiler out a bit with the type inference. Your reasoning about `MyTrait2#MyTraitType` of course is correct.

Another solution (going into the same category) is dropping the type of `obj`:

```
val obj = new MyTrait2Impl[MyTraitImpl]
```

But of course, that might not apply in your real use case.